# A lack of sim card in my android device crashing my apps? Why?

Tags: applications, 4.2-jelly-bean, sim-card, dual-sim

A weird problem I observed with my Micromax A116, android version 4.2.1.
From the day I bought it, 8 months back, I have used both the sim slots.
But the internal earphones were damaged & I couldn't listen to calls, so I bought a low-end Nokia phone & removed both sim cards from the Micromax phone.

I was using the android phone just for internet through a wifi connection. For 2 days, it was fine ie apps worked as usual. Then on the 3rd day, Twitter app started crashing while in use, often. Then the next day, Pocket stared crashing & relaunching. I updated both the apps, but the 
problem persisted. Then the inbuilt Galary app, facebook followed.
I guessed it may be a sim card issue. So reinserted one sim. The phone was back to
normal with no more crashes. After a few days , I again removed the sim card & used the apps, the same problem returned.

So the question is, was my guess correct that a lack of sim card was crashing my apps? If yes, then why is that so?